# R: set.seed() results don't match if caret package loaded

Tags: r, r-caret, random-seed

I am using `createFolds()` in R (version: 3.3.0) to create train/test partitions. To make results reproducible, I used `set.seed()` with a seed value of 10. As expected, the results (generated folds) were reproducible.

But once I loaded caret package just after setting the seed. And then used the createFolds function, I found that the created folds were different (although still reproducible).

Specifically, the created folds differ in the following two cases:

Case 1:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(10)
folds=createFolds(y,k=5,returnTrain=TRUE)
```

Case 2:

```
set.seed(10)
library(caret)
folds=createFolds(y,k=5,returnTrain=TRUE)
```

where `y` is a vector.

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is ggplot2, which is attached when you load caret. It defines an `.onAttach` function: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/zzz.r

This function is called when the package is attached, see `help("ns-hooks")`. And within it `runif` is called thereby advancing the state of the RNG.

Comment: A [similar question](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/452) came up the other day; some package use random numbers on startup

Comment: @topepo is there any way around this issue?  I have the same issue, but even if I set the seed after loading the caret package. Is this expected?.  I was hoping to use caret for createFolds, but I need a way to make it reproducible.  EDIT: I just realized I was not setting the seed in between different calls of `createFolds()`, that was the issue.